# mount webdav SSL at windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, ssl, webdav

I have a webdav server on my linux machine with SSL authentication. I can mount this webdav at localhost, at remote linux machine and also at remote MacOS machine. It ask to accept the certificate and it mount.
Now I am trying to mount at windows 10. First, windows does not show any certificate to be accept. I transfer the certificate created on some remote linux machine like this: `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect 145.117.144.230:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /etc/irods/ssl/145.117.144.230.crt` and installed at the windows 10. I have installed at local machine for all users. The Certificate store I have used was "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". I also have used "Intermediate Certification Authorities". All that I use shows that the certificated was imported successfully. So I try to map the network drive https://ugp-repmed.fedora20.ebiocloud.amc.nl with credentials user/pass and show this message:

`The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred: Mutual Authentication failed. The server's password is out of date at the domain controller.`

If I try to connect through the browser I can accept the certificate and I can access, but read-only. I need to map the network drive and this error is stucking me. Does anybody know how to solve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the authenticaton to the WebDAV server BASIC or DIGEST?  With Windows 10 I believe the redirector only support DIGEST unless you modify the registry.

Try setting a DWORD BasicAuthLevel in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters to "1"

Values are 0 (default) - 2

- 0 - Basic authentication disabled
- 1 - Basic authentication enabled for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) shares only
- 2 or greater - Basic authentication enabled for SSL shares and for non-SSL shares